# Has Syria received proportionally more refugees than other countries in recent history?

Tags: history, politics, syria, refugees

[This comment by Sonia Bous Aidi](https://www.facebook.com/humansofnewyork/photos/a.102107073196735.4429.102099916530784/1102246809849418/?type=3&comment_id=1102297496511016&offset=0&total_comments=3212&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R2%22%7D) on a recent [Humans of New York](https://www.facebook.com/humansofnewyork) post about the [European migrant crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_migrant_crisis) is powerful if true:

> Syria became home to the Circassian refugees in 1860
>
> Syria became home to the Armenian refugees in 1914
>
> Syria became home to the Palestinian refugees in 1948
>
> Syria became home once again to Palestinian refugees in 1967
>
> Syria became home to the refugees from Kuwait in 1990
>
> Syria became home to refugees from Lebanon in 1996
>
> Syria became home to the refugees from Iraq in 2003
>
> Syria became home to the refugees from Lebanon in 2006
>
> It will be written in the history books and generations will remember, that Syria never closed it’s borders for those who fled their homes seeking safety and refuge.
>
> Syria has never asked any Arab for a visa to enter it’s lands whether it was a visit or permanent stay.
>
> In Syria not a single tent was put up on the borders to accommodate for refugees across the years, houses were opened, streets were vacated and cities were renamed to allow for refugees to feel at home.
>
> Let it be written in the history books and let the generations remember, that when a Syrian needed help and refuge; borders were closed and the world looked away.

The claim is not specifically made, but the implication is clearly that in recent times, Syria has always welcomed refugees, and that it has received *proportionally more* refugees from nearby countries than other countries have received Syrian refugees.

**Is such an assertion correct?**

---

[Notability](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) support: The comment has 9346 likes, making it highly visible on the page. The comment has 264 replies disucssing it. [HoNY](https://www.facebook.com/humansofnewyork) has millions of readers worldwide. The perceived unfairness of having to deal with refugees when others do not is a major argument of policymakers seeking to limit refugee intake.

Comment: All the source says is that Syria received at least *some* refugees on all those occasions. It says nothing about "proportionally more refugees than other countries".

Comment: Also worth noting that Syria's open-door policy for refugees is strictly Arab-only. So who is this post criticising for not responding now? Other Arab countries?

Comment: I would be very surprised if Syria never asked a **permanent stay** visa for arabs.

Comment: The second from the last paragraph is 100% factually wrong at the very least for Palestinians.